# Spring JPA + Mysql, how to implement a SELECT, FROM, WHERE query?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I'm struggling to understand how to implement a simple query like

```
SELECT * from Orders where category=1 and userid=1
```

with Spring + JPA + Mysql.

I see that extending `JpaRepository` the query `findByUserId` and `findByCategory` are already implemented and working.
However, how do I add a simple filter to the basic query?
I cannot apply the filter to the result as it will be too big.

I am struggling to find the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extended JpaRepository, you can do something like this:

```
List<Order> findByUserIdAndCategory(Integer userId, Integer category);
```

You can take a look at JpaRepository query methods here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Glad to help! Take care

Comment: Check if you need to add @Param("....") to your method parameters

Comment: I don't think  `@Param` is necessary in this example. Isn't `@Param` intented for parameter binding by name for the `@Query` tag?